# Interfacing Shinymanager and Golem

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, golem

I would like to know if there is any documentation about interfacing golem structure and shinymanager which is a package I use frequently to secure my app. The shinymanager workflow proposed on their github works well with a Ui.R / Server.R arborescence by wrapping the UI object in the secure_app() function and calling the server part to get the credentials, which in my case is a database called ‘credentials.sqlite’ stored on the package directory.

Do you have any snippets for that ?

Thanks you very much.

Comment: Hey, did my answer solved the issue? If yes, could you accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, here is how to:

- Use `{shinymanager}` as a dep https://github.com/ColinFay/golemshinymanager/blob/master/dev/02_dev.R#L18
- Wrap your UI in `shinymanager::secure_app()` in `run_app()` https://github.com/ColinFay/golemshinymanager/blob/master/dev/02_dev.R#L18
- Check your credentials in app_server https://github.com/ColinFay/golemshinymanager/blob/master/R/app_server.R#L10

See https://github.com/ColinFay/golemshinymanager for the reprex

Cheers,
Colin

Comment: Colin, I tried this reprex but it does not work. The login page never shows up, unless I redefine it inside ```app_ui.R```. However, doing that throws an error when performing golem recommended tests. Any suggestions?

Comment: These repositories appear to have been deleted/moved, does anyone know where they live now?

Comment: @BryceRoney yep : https://github.com/ColinFay/golemexamples :)

Comment: @ColinFAY golem framework is fantastic. Thank you for your efforts!